# Nested comment system sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a comment system that i designed, and its working without any nesting.  Now i want to allow people to reply to comments directly rather than whatever the general thing is on that page.  So i thought about adding a parent id column in my database that would point to the parent id.

Now the next step (which i am havin issues finding a good way to go about this). Is to query the database for all comments (nested and not) all based on their common "thing id" and then display them in the correct order, so that the nested comments are connected to their parents properly...is there any efficient way to order all of these comments together so that i dont have to start doing weird query calls with recursion and stuff?  All the comments also have a time stamp along with some other irrelevant data.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Easyest way is to use two queries. First query you select all parent, and in the second their children. Or select them all at once, and put them in an array with the parent_id as key.

Comment: I know it's probably not a practical option, but it's still something to think about: this seems like a good use case for a [document-oriented database like MongoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB).  You could store all of the comments to the post within the post, and then nested comments on each comment within that comment. Querying all the data for some posting is as simple as grabbing the document—no joins required! However, the rest of your design might not work so nicely with MongoDB. But, like I said, it's something interesting to think about.

Comment: If nesting can be any level deep, than you possibly can't avoid recursion of some sort.  If you are more familiar with PHP, you can recurse on your array obtained from MySQL.

Comment: Please use the search. For the theory some fantastic answers exist already on this website some even with code-examples. It's just too complex and burdensome to answer it over and over again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a concept called "nested sets".  Basically, each comment and article would have two columns, specifying the "start" and "end" of its set of sub-items.  Every comment has a start and end that's entirely within the parent item's set, and there's no overlap between siblings -- the only time two sets overlap, is when one is entirely within the other (ie: if one item is a sub-item of the other).

```
                                   Article
                             /-----(1, 12)----\
                       Comment                 Comment
                   /---(2, 5)               /--(6, 11)--\
             Comment                    Comment        Comment
             (3, 4)                     (7, 8)         (9, 10)
```

When you do your query on a particular item, you look for every item with a matching article ID, whose set is within your item's set.  That retrieves all the children, and all their children, and so on.  Sort them by start or end, and the comments should even appear mostly in order -- and you can compare with the other endpoint to tell whether one is a sub-item of the other.  (If you've sorted by start, and this item's end is less than the previous one's, then you have a sub-item.)

Drawback is, every comment requires updating those sets.  It's pretty simple, but potentially very slow.  In order to add another item under (7,8), for example:

- For that article, update every 'end' >= 8 by adding 2 to it.
- For that article, update every 'start' > 8 by adding 2.
- Insert the new item, with a set of (8, 9).

The more comments you have "after" the one you're inserting, of course, the slower the updates will be.

Hold on..lemme google...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model